# Minka havenworth fan with tx and rx

Tags: electrical, wiring, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan has this for a wiring diagram. I have black, white, red and a ground wire in my ceiling. Should I be attaching the green/yellow to the red or the ground?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Green/Yellow is *always* ground

Green/Yellow so happens to be the *international* color code for protective earthing (grounding) wires; as thus, the NEC designates it as reserved for that purpose, too, even more so than plain green wire is!

So, connect the green/yellow wire to the ground wire, and cap the red wire off.  Also, make sure there's a wall-switch-controlled light *somewhere* in the room!